# Purpose of having abstract child by extending concrete parent

Tags: java, oop

Sometimes, I came across some class design as follow.

```
abstract class animal {
    public abstract void speak();
}

class dog extends animal {

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        // Do something.
    }

}

abstract class abstract_dog extends dog {
    @Override
    public abstract void speak();
}
```

---

I was wondering, what is the purpose of having an `abstract_dog` class? Why we "transform" the non-abstract speak method into abstract speak again?

Comment: Note: if you control the class hierarchy, a better approach would be either to eliminate the concrete dog class entirely, or have it subclass abstract_dog. Prefer to make non-leaf classes abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to create a base class that forces people to override `speak`, but inherits `Dog`.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I would still consider this a code smell, if I came across it during review.. (Still +1)

Comment: @nfechner: That completely depends on the specific situation.  I think I've needed to do this exactly one in 5+ years of development.

Comment: +1 for the simple reason, although your answer (as well as the question) lacks some real-life situation.

Comment: @SLaks A good reasoned, valid code smell is still one, as evidenced by the fact that you still remember that you needed to do this once. I think, one should treat this and acknowledge it as a hack and use it while putting a big disclaimer on top: "Children: Don't do this at home"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SLaks, and think that this would be a real life situation:

```
abstract class animal {
    public abstract void speak();
}

class dog extends animal {

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        // Dog says 'bark'
    }

}

abstract class abstract_dog extends dog {
    @Override
    public abstract void speak();
}

class poodle extends abstract_dog {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        // poodle says 'yip yip'
    }
}

class great_dane extends abstract_dog {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        // great dane says 'ruff ruff'
    }
}
```

I think you would use this in the case where you want the make a new child class implement the `speak` method and the `dog` class may have other methods that the new child class would not have to implement.
Knowing more about your exact situation would help in determining if there is a better design for this scenario.

Comment: But you can just as well skip abstract_dog in this example.

Comment: @Buhb, that is true, and it is a potential problem with this design.